# parse the uploaded file as an argument to python program Django

Tags: python, django

So right now I have written a python program which takes the path name as an argument from console to execute..
now I am trying to learn Django and am trying to execute same program but via the web browser.
So I figured out that let me have a form field to upload the file..
and then an execute button..
and when the execute button is pressed.. the program runs.. 
but how do I handle that uploaded file.. 
Sorry for this as I have no web-exeprience.. and I want to learn by getting my hands dirty.. :)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bunch of ways:

- [os.system(command)](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system)
- [os.popen(command[, mode[, bufsize]])](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen)
- [using subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) - subprocess.call(...)

and maybe others i don't know about. Be aware that exposing these features to the public invites abuse. You may be interested in [sandboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python) (or [this](http://wiki.python.org/moin/SandboxedPython) writeup) or using something like [pyjs](http://pyjs.org/) or [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) which can turn python into javascript and execute in browser.