# Compare strings with different operators in python

Tags: python

I'd like to compare two strings in a function with the comparison/membership operators as argument.

```
string1 = "guybrush"
string2 = "guybrush threepwood"

def compare(operator):
    print(string1 operator string2)
```

`compare(==)` should print `False` and
`compare(in)` should print `True`

It's obviously not working like that. Could I assign variables to the operators, or how would I solve that?

Comment: this question doesn't exactly answer your question. but it's explanations might help you understand how to do it. https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695773/7025986

Comment: Use **operator** : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983139/assign-operator-to-variable-in-python

Comment: Try this: http://tomerfiliba.com/blog/Infix-Operators/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass in operators directly, you need a function like so:

```
from operator import eq

string1 = "guybrush"
string2 = "guybrush threepwood"

def compare(op):
    print(op(string1, string2))

compare(eq)
>>>False
```

The in operator is a little more tricky, since `operator` doesn't have an `in` operator but does have a `contains`

`operator.contains(a, b)` is the same as `b in a`, but this won't work in your case since the order of the strings are set. In this case you can just define your own function:

```
def my_in(a, b): return a in b

compare(my_in)
>>>True
```

Comment: Great, thanks! In my case, I can just switch string1 and string2 within the function and use operator.contains.

Comment: @Matthias Happy to help :)