# How to pass an operator to a python function?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I'd like to pass a math operator, along with the numeric values to compare, to a function. Here is my broken code:

```
def get_truth(inp,relate,cut):    
    if inp print(relate) cut:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

and call it with

```
get_truth(1.0,'>',0.0)
```

which should return True.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Have a look at the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
get_truth(1.0, operator.gt, 0.0)

...

def get_truth(inp, relate, cut):    
    return relate(inp, cut)
    # you don't actually need an if statement here
```

Comment: In the end, I just got rid of my function and used operator. 'if operator.gt(1.0,0.0):'

Comment: Couldn't you just use `if 1.0 > 0.0:`?

Comment: I want to be able to change the operator dynamically (so I may have to go back to the function solution).

Comment: for `in` operator see `operator.contains(a,b)`. Note that this checks presence of b in a not the other way round.

Answer (score 59):

Make a mapping of strings and [operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) functions. Also, you don't need if/else condition:

```
import operator


def get_truth(inp, relate, cut):
    ops = {'>': operator.gt,
           '<': operator.lt,
           '>=': operator.ge,
           '<=': operator.le,
           '==': operator.eq}
    return ops[relate](inp, cut)


print(get_truth(1.0, '>', 0.0)) # prints True
print(get_truth(1.0, '<', 0.0)) # prints False
print(get_truth(1.0, '>=', 0.0)) # prints True
print(get_truth(1.0, '<=', 0.0)) # prints False
print(get_truth(1.0, '==', 0.0)) # prints False
```

FYI, `eval()` is evil: [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice)

Comment: +1. Also, this answer demonstrates that you can directly return the value of `ops[relate]`, instead of explicitly testing it and returning a literal `True` or `False`.

Comment: I recommend to replace `=` with `==`

Comment: Beautiful! But please use `==` for comparison!

Comment: Just for future reference, with this approach an implementer _could_ add a mapping for both `=` _and_ `==` in their `ops` dict, though I agree it’s probably better to get in the habit of using `==` over `=`… but also:  
  
I would also recommend adding some form of `if relate not in ops.keys: raise AnAppropriateError` or at least wrap the `return` in a `try` clause to meaningfully catch the inevitable call of the function with a typo or some other unrecognised input. Of course, how much "neatness" is desired might also depend on who the final enduser of the function will be. :)

Answer (score 14):

Use the `operator` module. It contains all the standard operators that you can use in python. Then use the operator as a functions:

```
import operator

def get_truth(inp, op, cut):
    return op(inp, cut):

get_truth(1.0, operator.gt, 0.0)
```

If you really want to use strings as operators, then create a dictionary mapping from string to operator function as @alecxe suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `operator` module instead:

```
import operator
def get_truth(inp, relate, cut):
    rel_ops = {
        '>': operator.gt,
        '<': operator.lt,
        '>=': operator.ge,
        '<=': operator.le,
        '==': operator.eq,
        '!=': operator.ne
    }
    return rel_ops[relate](inp, cut)
```

Comment: @PaulEvans: because mapping `<` to `operator.lt` is trivial.

Comment: Thanks @PaulEvans. I will go with the operator method for reasons desribed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice

Answer (score -4):

```
>>> def get_truth(inp,relate,cut):
...     if eval("%s%s%s" % (inp,relate,cut)):
...         return True
...     else:
...         return False
...
>>> get_truth(1.0,'>',0.0)
True
>>>
```

Comment: No, please don't use `eval()` when better solutions are available.

Comment: what is your problem with eval??? You are downvoting everybody who has given a working solution that uses eval

Comment: `eval()` poses a security risk, and is way overused as a 'solution' whenever people do not know a better option exists.

Comment: **[Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It [cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139)**