# Pandas series operator as function parameter

Tags: python, pandas

### Background

I want to perform a calculation on a Pandas Series. This calculation involves `min` and `max`. The calculation is used twice. In both cases it is the same calculation except for the `min` or `max` functions, which should be different.

I've created a function to perform this calculation:

```
def my_calc(my_series):
   return my_series.rolling(...).max()
```

### The problem

I don't know how to pass `max` as a parameter of `my_calc`.

### Attempts

- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591778/how-to-pass-an-operator-to-a-python-function) works only for basic operators.
- Currently I use `my_calc(my_series).max()` and `my_calc(my_series).min()`

Comment: what is wrong with `my_calc(my_series).max()` & `my_calc(my_series).min()` if `my_calc()` returns `rolling` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really no pretty way to do it.

```
def my_calc(my_series, func=max):
   if not func in {'min', 'max'}:
      raise ValueError('{} is not a valid method name!'.format(func))
   return getattr(my_series.rolling(...), func)()

foo = my_calc(some_series, 'min')
bar = my_calc(some_series, 'max')
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `my_calc` with the name of the function as string, then use `getattr`:

```
def my_calc(my_series, func_name):
    try:
        return getattr(my_series.rolling(...), func_name)()
    except AttributeError:
        print('{} has no attribute {}'.format(type(my_series), func_name))

my_calc(my_series, 'min')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this  `rolling_max`

```
def my_calc(my_series):
  return my_series.rolling_max(...)
```

Comment: `FutureWarning: pd.rolling_min is deprecated for Series and will be removed in a future version, replace with 
 Series.rolling(window=4320,center=False).min()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply (or agg):

```
def my_calc(my_series, func):
   return my_series.rolling(...).apply(func)
```

And use like:

```
my_calc(ser, np.mean)
Out[321]: 
0    NaN
1    0.5
2    0.0
3    0.5
4    2.0
Name: a, dtype: float64
```