# How to send a formula and not a result?

Tags: python, python-3.x

What happens is that when I use the functions like `sum()` Python says me that it doesn't exist. Because **it's trying to send a numeric result instead of the formula, as I want**. Somebody knows any way to make it work??

```
def calculator(action, formula):
    print('I need two numberst to {} them'.format(accion))
    a = int( input('Enter the first term'))
    b = int( input('Enter the second term'))

def sum():
    calculator('add', a+b)

def substraccion():
    calculator('substract', a-b)

def multimplication():
    calculator('multiply', a*b)

def division():
    calculator('divide', a/b)

# --- MAIN --- #

sum()
```

Comment: You want to return a function from another function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no thing called *"formula"* in Python. `a + b` is an expression and it does not do what you think it does.

When encountered, `a + b` is evaluated by examining types of `a` and `b` to determine how to calculate `+` operation. At that point, both `a` and `b` variables must exist and be initialised to something that can be summed.

What you call a *"formula"* is most similar to a function. So, you can create a function:

```
def plus(x, y):
    return x + y
```

This function does what you want, e.g.

```
>>> plus(5, 6)
11
>>> plus(2, -5)
-3
```

Now, you can send that function to the `calculator`:

```
def calculator(action_name, function):
    print('I need two numbers to {} them'.format(action_name))
    a = int( input('Enter the first term: '))
    b = int( input('Enter the second term: '))
    result = function(a, b)
    print('The result is {}'.format(result))

def sum():
    calculator('add', plus)
```

BTW, I would not call my function `sum`, because there is a built-in function named `sum`, which you hide when you create your own. Choose a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here: [How to pass an operator to a python function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18591778/how-to-pass-an-operator-to-a-python-function)

You can't just type a+b as parameter and think that python is gonna understand that you want to pass an operator

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a lambda function
Ex:
Calculator ('add', lambda x,y:x+y)