# Map operators extracted from substring

Tags: python, regex, substring, operators, list-comprehension

I have `list of dict`s:

```
print (L)
[{0: 'x==1', 1: 'y==2', 2: 'z!=1'}, {0: 'x==1', 1: 'y<=3', 2: 'z>1'}]
```

I want create tuples with value before operators, operators and value after:

```
#first step
wanted = [[('x', '==', '1'), ('y', '==', '2'), ('z', '!=', '1')], 
          [('x', '==', '1'), ('y', '<=', '3'), ('z', '>', '1')]]
```

And then map second value by operators:

```
import operator

ops = {'>': operator.gt,
        '<': operator.lt,
       '>=': operator.ge,
       '<=': operator.le,
       '==': operator.eq,
        '!=': operator.ne}

#expected final output
wanted = [[('x', <built-in function eq>, '1'), 
           ('y', <built-in function eq>, '2'), 
           ('z', <built-in function ne>, '1')], 
          [('x', <built-in function eq>, '1'), 
           ('y', <built-in function le>, '3'), 
           ('z', <built-in function gt>, '1')]]
```

I try:

```
L = [[re.findall(r'(.*)([<>=!]+)(.*)', v)[0] for k, v in x.items()] for x in L]
print (L)
[[('x=', '=', '1'), ('y=', '=', '2'), ('z!', '=', '1')], 
 [('x=', '=', '1'), ('y<', '=', '3'), ('z', '>', '1')]]

L = [[ops[y[1]] for y in x] for x in L]
```

But problem is wrong matched middle substrings - operators and then wrong matched value of operator.

What is corrct regex for correct match? Or here is some another possible solution. e.g. by `string.partition` ? I am open all possible solutions.

Comment: Instead of greedy for first substring use `r'(\w)([<>=!]+)(.*)'` or `r'(\w+)([<>=!]+)(.*)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most straightforward approach, if your inputs are indeed this simple, is to *split* on the operator characters:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: data = [{0: 'x==1', 1: 'y==2', 2: 'z!=1'}, {0: 'x==1', 1: 'y<=3', 2: 'z>1'}]

In [3]: rgx = re.compile(r'([<>=!]+)')

In [4]: [[rgx.split(v) for v in d.values()] for d in data]
Out[4]:
[[['x', '==', '1'], ['y', '==', '2'], ['z', '!=', '1']],
 [['x', '==', '1'], ['y', '<=', '3'], ['z', '>', '1']]]
```

Note, if you add a capturing group to the splitter regex, it gets included!

And then, to finish it out:

```
In [11]: ops = {'>': operator.gt,
    ...:         '<': operator.lt,
    ...:        '>=': operator.ge,
    ...:        '<=': operator.le,
    ...:        '==': operator.eq,
    ...:         '!=': operator.ne}
    ...:

In [12]: parsed = [[rgx.split(v) for v in d.values()] for d in data]

In [13]: [[(x, ops[op], y) for x,op,y in ps] for ps in parsed]
Out[13]:
[[('x', <function _operator.eq>, '1'),
  ('y', <function _operator.eq>, '2'),
  ('z', <function _operator.ne>, '1')],
 [('x', <function _operator.eq>, '1'),
  ('y', <function _operator.le>, '3'),
  ('z', <function _operator.gt>, '1')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the greedy method 1st substring regex to the only word character :

```
L = [{0: 'x==1', 1: 'y==2', 2: 'z!=1'}, {0: 'x==1', 1: 'y<=3', 2: 'z>1'}]
L = [[re.findall(r'(\w)([<>=!]+)(.*)', v)[0] for k, v in x.items()] for x in L]
[[(y[0],ops[y[1]],y[2]) for y in x] for x in L]

[[('x', <function _operator.eq>, '1'),
  ('y', <function _operator.eq>, '2'),
  ('z', <function _operator.ne>, '1')],
 [('x', <function _operator.eq>, '1'),
  ('y', <function _operator.le>, '3'),
  ('z', <function _operator.gt>, '1')]]
```

Or as per [`jezrael`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2901002/jezrael) suggestion from comments (1 line list comprehesion):

```
L = [[[(z[0], ops[z[1]], z[2]) for z in re.findall(r'(\w)([<>=!]+)(.*)', v)][0] for k, v in x.items()] for x in L]
```

Or we don't need keys so using values directly:

```
L = [[[(z[0], ops[z[1]], z[2]) for z in re.findall(r'(\w)([<>=!]+)(.*)', v)][0] for v in x.values()] for x in L]
```

Comment: Maybe is possible create one line solution like `L = [[[(z[0], ops[z[1]], z[2]) for z in re.findall(r'(\w)([<>=!]+)(.*)', v)][0] 
          for k, v in x.items()] for x in L]`

Comment: @jezrael Sure, Will add that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `*` is a greedy character matcher. So, in `x==1`, if `*` can match more than one character, it will, while still satisfying the second group `([<>=!]+)` with a single `=` character.

Solutions:

1. Assuming the non-operator groups will never include `<`, `>`, `=` or `!`, instead of using `*`, use negative character set:

   `re.findall(r'([^<>=!]+)([<>=!]+)([^<>=!]+)', v)`
2. Use alternation with the vertical bar for capturing the operator:

   `re.findall(r'(.*)((?:>|<|<=|>=|==|!=))(.*)', v)`