# changing only the operator in python code

Tags: python

I have a piece of code that is repeating with only a math operator changing, i.e:

```py
x1=a+b
x2=a-b
x3=a*b
x4=a/b
```

is there a way to write a function that receives the operator and only applies that and thus eliminate the need to write almost the same code many times?

hopefully, something like:

```py
def operator_modularity(op):
    return a op b

operator_modularity(+)
```

Comment: Create a dictionary of operators from the [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) module and pass the key.

Comment: There is a standard `operator` module containing functions like `operator.add()`.  Your code would be `op(a, b)` if passed one of these functions as `op`.

Comment: i'm curious, what are you trying to do?

Comment: Where do the `a` and `b` come from in `operator_modularity`?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid the assignment of mas variables?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/18591860/14310038
......................................
...... ....

Comment: d.b say they are constants for example
UlisesBussi building a basic calculator but with modular code instead of the naive code duplication solution

Comment: @FaikaMajid how does that help ?

Answer (score 3):

```
def operator_modularity(op):
    return eval(f"10 {op} 10")

operator_modularity("+")
```

Comment: eval is evil, it allows more than i want
but it's a good direction tough, maybe combining it with the dictionary solution will give  a safe and modular piece of code.

Comment: lots of fun ahead! Yep, eval is evil: use for instance `op = " in [print('you have been hacked') for x in range(1)] #"` and have fun

Answer (score 2):

A great thing about Python is that you can keep pointers to methods.
Another cool thing is the built in `operators` module that gives you method-call shaped references to said operators. So to do that, you could run the following:

```
def foo(a, b):
     operators_to_run = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul]
     for op in operators_to_run:
         print(op(a,b))
```

There's no code repetition, and you get all the operators' results sequentially :)
I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could write some code like

```
def all_four_operations(num1, num2):
    return (num1 + num2, num1 - num2, num1 * num2, num1 / num2)

result_array = all_four_operations(1, 7)
x1 = result_array[0] # x1 = 8
x2 = result_array[1] # x2 = -6
x3 = result_array[2] # x3 = 7
x4 = result_array[3] # x4 = 0.14
```

Comment: You could probably do `return {"+": num1 + num2, "-": num1 - num2, "*": num1 * num2, "/": num1 / num2}`

Comment: this is still not preventing code duplication