# Is there pure python code that can break out of an execfile with local and global arguments?

Tags: python

Is there pure python code that can break out of an execfile with local and global arguments?

I was under the impression that nothing is "private" in python. But if I execute a piece of python code (with execfile) and capture the execution results in local and global namespace arguments, I am unaware of how you'd grab the scope of the main executable.

Thanks,
Chenz

Comment: What do you mean by "break out"?

Comment: I guess I'm thinking when you run something like execfile(script, {}, {}), its almost like running a sandbox (for pure python). So from this psuedo sandbox context, how can I modify my caller's environment?

Comment: A sandbox is difficult.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python).

Comment: I'm looking for potential for a trusted user to do something "clever" that results in subverting the intention of the mechanism.

Comment: @TimPeters I'm not trying to create a sandbox for security...

Comment: @CrazyChenz, then please edit your question to explain what you *are* trying to accomplish.  It's clear as mud ;-)

Comment: The try: raise except: is a good enough answer for me. Its pure python and gets me the callers frame. Still would be nice to see a proof of concept though.

Answer (score 2):

If by "break out", you mean access the Python objects in the calling code, then I'm not sure.

But if by break out, you mean

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['rm', '-rf', '/'])
```

then definitely yes it can.

Look at [pysandbox](https://github.com/haypo/pysandbox). Its authors have gone to a lot of work to sandbox `eval` and friends. I'd go there first if you actually wanted to do this.

Comment: "I am unaware of how you'd grab the scope of the main executable."

Comment: @PaulDraper, the code can simply raise an exception and catch it, then dig into the traceback object's internals to muck with anything up the call chain.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.  File `beast.py`:

```
import inspect
for i, t in enumerate(inspect.stack()):
    if i == 1:
        print 'i in the caller is', t[0].f_globals['i']
        t[0].f_globals['i'] = 666
        t[0].f_globals['j'] = -13
```

And file `xxx.py`:

```
i = 1
execfile("beast.py", {}, {})
print i
print j
```

Then:

```
$ python xxx.py
i in the caller is 1
666
-13
```

It doesn't do any good to prevent importing `inspect`.  The same things can be done by mucking with traceback objects directly.  If you want to know how, study `inspect.py` ;-)