# Adding multiple elements to a list in Python

Tags: python, list, input, append, python-3.4

I am trying to write something in Python that will be like a piano. Each number that the user enters will play a different sound.

1. The user is prompted for how many keys they want to be able to press (iterations).
2. They will be prompted for a number for a sound the same amount of times as they entered for iterations. Each number is a different sound.
3. It will play the sounds.

I am having trouble with the `userNum` function. I need all of the numbers that they enter for sounds to append to a list, and then another function will read the list and play each sound accordingly. This is what I have so far:

```
#Gets a user input for each sound and appends to a list.
def userNum(iterations):
  for i in range(iterations):
    a = eval(input("Enter a number for sound: "))
  myList = []
  while True:
    myList.append(a)
    break
  print(myList)
  return myList
```

This is what the printed list looks like with the code that I have so far:

```
>>> userNum(5)
Enter a number for sound: 1
Enter a number for sound: 2
Enter a number for sound: 3
Enter a number for sound: 4
Enter a number for sound: 5
[5]
```

Any thoughts of a way to get it to append each number to the list, or if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You create the list *after* the `for` loop, then have a `while` loop that only runs once. Why not create the list *before* the `for` loop, and `append` inside it? Also, you should use `int` not `eval`.

Comment: **[Do not ever use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice). It [cannot easily be sandboxed, and proper sandboxing is harder than using a proper tool for the job.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you should do in your function is initialize an empty list. Then you can loop the correct number of times, and within the `for` loop you can `append` into `myList`. You should also avoid using `eval` and in this case simply use `int` to convert to an integer.

```
def userNum(iterations):
    myList = []
    for _ in range(iterations):
        value = int(input("Enter a number for sound: "))
        myList.append(value)
    return myList
```

Testing

```
>>> userNum(5)
Enter a number for sound: 2
Enter a number for sound: 3
Enter a number for sound: 1
Enter a number for sound: 5
Enter a number for sound: 9
[2, 3, 1, 5, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

def userNum(iterations):

```
number_list = []

while iterations > 0:
    number = int(input("Enter a number for sound : "))
    number_list.append(number)
    iterations = iterations - 1
return number_list
```

print "Numbers List - {0}".format(userNum(5))

Enter a number for sound : 9

Enter a number for sound : 1

Enter a number for sound : 2

Enter a number for sound : 0

Enter a number for sound : 5

Numbers List - [9, 1, 2, 0, 5]

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return a list comp:

```
def userNum(iterations):
    return [int(input("Enter a number for sound: ")) for _ in range(iterations) ]
```

If you were using a loop you should use a while loop and verify input with a try/except:

```
def user_num(iterations):
    my_list = []
    i = 0
    while i < iterations:
        try:
            inp = int(input("Enter a number for sound: "))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")
            continue
        i += 1
        my_list.append(inp)
    return my_list
```