# How can I give users the possibility to write scripts (in a secure way)?

Tags: python

I currently have the problem where I need to write a function which receives a dictionary where all values are strings or dictionarys and outputs a string. The problem is the logic for creating this output string. I would like to let the user write the logic.

Now, of course, I could just ask the user to create a valid Python script with a function

```
def generate_string(input_dict):
    # your logic
    return "some_string"
```

The problem is that I don't want the users to be able to execute arbitrary code. Especially working with the file system (reading / writing / deleting files) should not be possible. There should also be a limit in the computation time / memory usage.

Is this possible?

Currently, I let them enter a format string. But this seems to be too limited as it misses `if` statements.

### Example

This is just a minimal, abstract example:

```
def generate_string(input_dict):
    if input_dict['type'] == 1:
        return "I want my date in {d:%Y%m%d}".format(d=input_dict['date'])
    elif input_dict['type'] == 2:
        return "type is {}".format(input_dict['type'])
    return "some_string"

d = {'type': 1, 'date': datetime.date(2017, 1, 14)}
generate_string(d)
```

Comment: What kind of "logic" ? Turing-complete logic? Just some arithmetic? Something else?

Comment: You could parse the output script avoiding `import` for examples... In that way you will, for example, block people from importing the os module.

Comment: not a close-voter, but this question is definitely quite broad. You haven't provided the method you've currently applied, nor any sample inputs and/or outputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sandbox Python in pure Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python)

Comment: Perhaps you need a restricted language, and a [parser](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) for that language.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Working with strings. Comparing (probably not even regex), `.lower()`, `.startswith()`, `.endswith()`, `if` statements. No arithmentic.

Comment: @MartinThoma Is something like Sed can do what you are looking for?

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm not sure. I don't think sed can have if statements, can it?

Comment: "if" statements are not necessary for making conditions. This is why a more strict definition of the required functionality is needed. Can it be described as a grammar?

Answer (score 2):

Python is not an easy language to lock down. Since it has a powerful introspection api, it is hard, if not impossible to block all system calls.

The only secure approach I can think of is to run the scripts on a separate environment, such as a docker container or a vm dedicated to running the scripts.

There is also pypy which can be run in sandboxed mode, but it is still a prototype and it might need a bit more work before being completely usable.

On the python wiki, there is a page about sandboxing python
https://wiki.python.org/moin/Asking%20for%20Help/How%20can%20I%20run%20an%20untrusted%20Python%20script%20safely%20%28i.e.%20Sandbox%29

PyPy sandboxing:
http://pypy.org/features.html#sandboxing

Also, take a look at [How can I sandbox Python in pure Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python#answer-3068475) which has an awesome answer to this same question.

Comment: FWIW, some of the difficulties of locking down Python are discussed in [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).