# Load python source code into function object

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to create a unit-test like framework for light-weight auto grading of single-function python assignments. I'd love to do something like the following:

```
test = """
def foo(x):
    return x * x
"""

compiled_module = magic_compile(test)
result = compiled_module.foo(3)
assert result == 9
```

Is there such a `magic_compile` function? The best I have so far is

```
exec(test)
result = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'foo')(3)
```

But this seems dangerous and unstable. This won't be run in production, so I'm not super-concerned about sandboxing and safety. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a better solution I'm missing.

Comment: Running an arbitrary function isn't any less dangerous than `exec`ing arbitrary code - you have to take the same precautions in both cases against malicious behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think there's an easy way to sandbox python [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068475/816458). I guess my larger concern is how to load it into an object that I can call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 3.x:

```
module = {}
exec(test, module)
assert module['foo'](3) == 9
```

`module` isn't a real Python module, it's just a namespace to hold the code's globals to avoid polluting your module's namespace.