# Safer `eval` in Python?

Tags: python, eval

**How can I make this code safer?** It is a minimal reproducible example of a more complex code where the internal users are allowed read access to a few dictionaries in the code, whose names are known in advance. The example works as intended with `eval`, and prevents *some* malicious user input, such as a system call to `rm -rf /`. But I was looking for a safer method than `eval`.

```python
import re

# In the minimal example, I have 2 dicts that the users need 
# read access to, and keys match this regex: ^\w+$
dct_a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
dct_b = {'baz': 3, 'bletch': 4}

# User input, e.g.:
lst = ["dct_a['foo']", "dct_b['baz']"]

for item in lst:
    # Make safer, prevent a few obvious hacks:
    if not re.findall(r"^[\w\]\[']+$", item):
        raise Exception(f'Unsafe item: {item}')
    # do something with item, e.g.:
    print(eval(item))

# Prints:
# 1
# 3
```

---

**I am aware that [`eval` is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), no need to repeat the warnings.**

**RELATED:**
[Python: make eval safe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3513292/967621)

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3068139/3001761

Comment: If it's only about accessing keys in defined dicts, you could create your own mini-language which only allows dict key access. E.g. `d, k = 'dct_a.foo'.split('.'); {'dct_a': dct_a, ...}[d][k]`…

Comment: I think it would be better to alter the requirements of the program so `eval` isn't needed. Blacklists just lead to "arms races" with attackers. A simple parser that does specifically what you need would be cleaner in the long run, if your problem can't be reduced down to simply accessing dictionaries normally.

Comment: @deceze: In the simplest case, this is all that's needed. If you expand the comment into an answer, I will be happy to accept it!

Comment: @Carcigenicate: That's my question precisely, how to replace the `eval` with the (hopefully not too complex) parser (or anything else safer than `eval`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of starting with the full power of Python and trying to rein it in (which is a fool's errand), start with only what you need, which doesn't allow the user to do anything else because it *can't* do anything else. You don't want your user to be able to run Python code, you want your user to be able to specify "variable values" in some very limited fashion. So, for example:

```
vals = {
    'a': {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2},
    'b': {'baz': 3, 'bletch': 4}
}

# User input, e.g.:
lst = ["a.foo", "b.baz"]

for item in lst:
    dct, k = item.split('.')
    print(vals[dct][k])
```

If that's all your users need to be able to do, that's all you need. From here you can of course start to write your own mini-language for more and more powerful, yet still very limited and restricted expressions. There are libraries like [pyparsing](https://pypi.org/project/pyparsing/) for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

To access variables (#safely) you can use `vars()` function
And regex to add more functionality to it:

```
import re

dct_a = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
dct_b = {'baz': 3, 'bletch': 4}

for _ in range(5):
    try:
        cmd = input(">>> ")
        cmds = re.findall(r'(\w+)\[\'?\"?(\w+)\'?\"?\]',cmd)
        if cmds:
            print(vars()[cmds[0][0]][cmds[0][1]])
        else:
            print(vars()[cmd])
    except Exception as e:
        print(cmd,'Not in Scope')
```

`vars()` returns a dictionary, of all the variable-names as *keys* and their value as *values* ,in that scope. In this case as I have used `vars` without any arguments and so it is equivalent to `locals()`, and can be used instead of `vars` as well.

`globals()` is a similar method, but as the name suggests, it access to only global variables.

Output:

```
>>> dct_a
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}

>>> dct_a['bar']
2

>>> dct_b
{'baz': 3, 'bletch': 4}

>>> dct_b["baz"]
3

>>> dct_c
dct_c Not in Scope
```