# Prevent python subprocess.Popen() from starting another processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

I have python code that starts new process with code:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(["python3", "solution.py"])
```

But code in solution.py can contain opening new processes:

```
import os
while True: os.fork()
```

How do I deny permission of subprocess to start new processes?

Comment: Are these subprocesses you're running from an untrusted source? If they are written by people that you trust to not fork infinite processes then I would think that you wouldn't need to deny permission, and if they are from an untrusted source then I would recommend against running the code at all, even with process creation permissions removed.

Comment: iirc, there's no OS level permission to restrict a process for creating sub-processes. That leaves possibly setting an env for the Popen which has key things stripped out of it, but [sandboxing python by controlling the env is notoriously hard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068139/how-can-i-sandbox-python-in-pure-python).