# Python exec user code on server - os command injection

Tags: python, code-injection

I have a project where a user can provide a python script that will be execute on the server to verify if the script is valid according to some criteria. I use the `exec` function to execute the code but it's vulnerable. User can use the os module in the script.

Is there a way to prevent command injection ? By preventing some modules to be used in `exec` ? Or another way to execute python code without risking injections ?

Thanks !

Comment: here's a guide that has tips: https://realpython.com/python-exec/ a big tip though, is: if you are using `exec`, make it run on the enduser/submitter's computer, not on your server, or you will be vulnerable. sounds like that is exactly what you want to do, so will probably carry some risk

Comment: Even if you prevent OS command injection, it could still uses python built-in functions and libraries to cause extensive problems. User-supplied code should be run in a temporary virtual machine to prevent them from doing damage.

Comment: Safe exec is really really hard in python, because a series of attribute accesses from innocuous types like `str` gets you to dangerous classes and modules

Comment: @JiříBaum, do you have a link/search term? Curious to see how that works.

Comment: The comments on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068259/683329) suggest `().__class__.__base__.__subclasses__()` which gives all the classes and then picking any class by name; they use it to construct a `code` object. [This reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/hftnp/comment/c1v372r/) uses the same trick to get back to the `builtins` module. I think I've seen others that take a more direct path from `str` to opening a file, although I can't quickly find it.

Comment: On another level, Python used to come with a [`rexec` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/rexec.html) in the standard library, which has been deprecated and removed; even the authors of the standard library, with all the expertise and the relationship with python core, could not find a way to get it to work. Python is just too dynamic and has too much introspection available.

Comment: So, the question is what to do next; part of that depends on who the users are and what criteria you want to check. It's possible to safely compile code to an AST, then check some properties from that; static analysis, basically. Are the criteria amenable to static checking?

Comment: The other way is to go the system way, with chroot jails and docker containers and VMs; those have their own challenges, but they have been done more successfully

Comment: @JiříBaum have you a link or something on the way to do this with chroot jails, docker containers or VMs ?

Comment: @JiříBaum I want to check if a function exists in the code and get the results of that function if exists

Comment: Easy enough to check whether a function exists; however, getting the result would involve running the code, at which point it's vulnerable